# How to repeat same value based on month date in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

anyone can help me doing this in bigquery? So i have 2 table like this

```
01/01/2000
01/02/2000
01/03/2000
01/04/2000
```

and this

```
start      | end        | status
01/01/2000 | 01/02/2000 | a
01/02/2000 | 01/06/2000 | b
```

i want them become like this

```
month      | status        
01/01/2000 | a
01/02/2000 | b
01/03/2000 | b
01/04/2000 | b
```

Comment: not clear the meaning of `end` field in second table ... can  you clarify? is it inclusive/exclusive/else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this with a between in the join.  The only caveat is how to handle the overlap of dates.  In this case I've subtracted a day from the end to not include it in the range.

```
with temp1 as(
select '01/01/2000' dt UNION ALL
select '01/02/2000' UNION ALL
select '01/03/2000' UNION ALL
select '01/04/2000' 
),
temp2 as (
select '01/01/2000' start, '01/02/2000' end_dt, 'a' status UNION ALL
select '01/02/2000' start, '01/06/2000' end_dt, 'b' status
)
select *
from temp1
join temp2
 on parse_date('%d/%m/%Y',temp1.dt) between parse_date('%d/%m/%Y',temp2.start) and date_add(parse_date('%d/%m/%Y', temp2.end_dt), interval -1 day)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select month, status
from `project.dataset.tableA`
join `project.dataset.tableB`
on parse_date('%d/%m/%Y', month) >= parse_date('%d/%m/%Y', start)
and parse_date('%d/%m/%Y', month) < parse_date('%d/%m/%Y', `end`)
```

If to apply to sample data in your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.tableA` as (
  select '01/01/2000' month union all
  select '01/02/2000' union all
  select '01/03/2000' union all
  select '01/04/2000' 
), `project.dataset.tableB` as (
  select '01/01/2000' start, '01/02/2000' `end`, 'a' status union all
  select '01/02/2000', '01/06/2000', 'b' 
)
select month, status
from `project.dataset.tableA`
join `project.dataset.tableB`
on parse_date('%d/%m/%Y', month) >= parse_date('%d/%m/%Y', start)
and parse_date('%d/%m/%Y', month) < parse_date('%d/%m/%Y', `end`)
```

output is

[image]

And btw, since mid October 2020 - BigQuery standard SQL supports DATE [arithmetic operators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#date_arithmetics_operators). So, below will also work

```
#standardSQL
select month, status
from `project.dataset.tableA`
join `project.dataset.tableB`
on parse_date('%d/%m/%Y', month) 
   between parse_date('%d/%m/%Y', start) 
   and parse_date('%d/%m/%Y', `end`) - 1
```